Why didn't/don't all chess armageddon have auction?
Quote:

Armageddon Chess is a fair tie-break system only if the two players bid for how much time Black should have.
Foolishly most times I see Armageddon specified there is no bidding. Instead the Tournament Organizer gazes into his magic oracle which tells him the exactly correct fair amount of time to give to Black (the T.O. is careful to never let us see the oracle for ourselves). This no-bid foolishness amazes me.

Yeah, why is this - like why wasn't chess armageddon like xiangqi armageddon w/c afaik always had auction?
